# Two random variable density functions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm new to this site and was wondering if anyone could help me on a math question!

I am currently studying probability and statistics and have come across a challenging question for me. See link below.

So previous I have worked with joint density functions in order to determine probabilities but I'm afraid I'm totally stuck when dealing with independent density functions.

Could anyone help me on this matter please. Kind regards.

> Suppose that the random variable $X$ has density
> $$
> f_X(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x}{2}, & 0<x<2 \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> and suppose that the random variable $Y$ has density
> $$
> f_Y(y) =
> \begin{cases}
> 4y^3, & 0<y<1 \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> also suppose that the variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
>
> Determine $P(Y>X)$ to three decimal places.

[question link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7qSQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to the site x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer:

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>X]=\int_{0}^{1}f_Y(y)\Bigg[\int_0^y f_X(x)dx\Bigg]dy$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So does this mean I integrate $f_X(x)$ which is $\frac{x}{2}$ between the boundaries of $y$ and 0 which gives me $\frac{y^2}{4}$ and then use the next integral and do the integral of $y^5$ between the boundaries 1 and 0 and get the answer 0.167 to 3d.p.?

Comment: @Xxx : perfect! I hope you understood the way to proceed, in general, not only for this problem. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: Thank you! I certainly did and have now clicked the check mark for you.